# How do you change Google Apps e-mail address sender name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/index1.html) for my domain email and I noticed when I receive an email from my application It gives the email domain name instead of my apps name. For example in Gmail, users receive email from `info@myapp.com` and it shows:

```
Info    info@myapp.com
```

When I want it to show `MyApp info@myapp.com`

How would I change the google apps sender name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually can be managed inside of your application with Ruby on Rails. Not sure about Google Apps though. Anyways I got it working by putting inside of my `user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "'MySite.com' <info@mysite.com>"
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to MySite")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Gmail ( or Google Apps) does not let you alter your From name when relaying email. However, you might be able to go into your mail settings (log into the Google Apps info account) and change the name there.